# Cannot call a method from the same file

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def a():
    response = rannum(14)
    print("Number: " + response)

def rannums(x):
    random(x)
```

it is saying that the object is not callable and I am having a hard time figuring out how to get this to work

Comment: *What* object isn't callable, and what should happen were this to "work"?

Comment: @ScottHunter I am basically trying to make a method that will return back a random number with the length of the argument (x). So in this case I am trying to get it to display a 14 digit number

Comment: @B.Simmons no, he asks what exact object is not callable. What does error say. I guess it will be `module`.

Comment: @sashaaero yes its module

Comment: @B.Simmons Please provide the full [repro] together with the full error message it generates.

Answer (score 0):

`rannums` calls `random`, which isn't defined anywhere.  `a` calls `rannum`, which isn't defined anywhere.  Neither `a` nor `rannums` are called from anywhere.

Comment: I should have been more clear, but these are methods that are called. I just took this tiny snippet out of a much larger thing I am working on

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment (" I am basically trying to make a method that will return back a random number with the length of the argument (x)"):

**This is copy and paste from ipython interactive shell – you have to retype, if you want to use it**

```
In [1]: from random import choices; from string import digits                   

In [2]: def get_random_number_with_length(length): 
   ...:     return int(''.join(choices(digits, k=length))) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [3]: get_random_number_with_length(13)                                       
Out[3]: 8677100367579
```

or maybe better:

```
In [1]: from random import randint                                              

In [2]: def get_random_number_with_length(length): 
   ...:     return randint(10**(length-1), (10**length) -1) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [3]: get_random_number_with_length(3)                                        
Out[3]: 806
```

and your error is that you are calling the module `random` and not the function `random.random(x)`, or do `from random import random`.